# How to draw Control flow graph and Cyclomatic complexity for this class?

Tags: c#, control-flow-graph

```
public class Wheel{
   public int faceValue;
   public string[ ] fruitNames=new string[5];
   public Wheel(string[ ] fruits){
     for(int i=0; i<fruits.Length; i++){
       fruitNames[i]=fruits[i];
     }
   }

   public void Spin( ) {
     Random rdm=new Random( );
     faceValue=rdm.Next(5);
   }

   public string GetFaceValue( ){
    return fruitNames[faceValue];
   }
 }
```

How to calculate Cyclomatic complexity for this program? So I need to draw cfg.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Java, so have retagged. Would you explain a bit more what help you are looking for?

Comment: This is c# code. I would like to know how to draw control flow graph and then how to calculate Cyclomatic Complexity for this Wheel class?

Comment: I wonder if two things would help here: showing how you are calling this instantiating and calling this class, and showing your attempt at drawing the CFG. Can you explain where you are stuck?